# Custom Button using Stack

Tags: flutter, widget, containers, flutter-animation

[image: How to create button using stack widgets and curved desgin with out background images]

How to create button using stack widgets and curved desgin with out background images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it helps :)

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            image: const DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/button_background.png',
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: RawMaterialButton(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            splashColor: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () {
              print('Hello World');
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: const Text('Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using background images because it's simpler, but if you really insist on not using them, here is an example of how to do it without background image:

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 250,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.green, Colors.yellow],
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
              ),
            ),
            child: RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              splashColor: Colors.green,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 5,
                    top: -80,
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: -40,
                    top: -65,
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        color: Colors.brown.withOpacity(.9),
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

P.S. feel free to adjust the `color`s and `height/width` values to your needs.

Comment: background image easy to use but i learned new widget so only im asked Thank you so much bro